# Nginx error log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a Digital Ocean droplet, which houses my Meteor application, but I keep getting this error in my `/var/log/nginx` logs:

`2015/03/11 12:58:46 [error] 2114#0: *423 "/usr/share/nginx/www/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 199.223.125.109,         server: nickeleres.com, request$`

My application doesnt require an entry point; beyond that, I have no idea where in my config this directive is coming from.  Im following this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

And Ive even commented out these lines from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nickeleres`:

```
#root /usr/share/nginx/html; # root is irrelevant
#index index.html index.htm; # this is also irrelevant
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**  my nginx config

```
           server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

            # this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
            map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
                default upgrade;
                ''      close;
            }

            # HTTP
            server {
                listen 80 default_server; # if this is not a default server, remove "default_server"
                listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

                #root /home/nickeleres; # root is irrelevant
                #index /home/nickeleres; # this is also irrelevant

                server_name nickeleres.com; # the domain on which we want to host the application. Since we set "default_server" previously, nginx will answer all hosts anyway.

                # redirect non-SSL to SSL
                location / {
                    rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
                }
            }

            # HTTPS server
            server {
                listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
                server_name nickeleres.com; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate

                #root /home/nickeleres; # irrelevant
                #index /home/nickeleres; # irrelevant

                ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nickeleres.pem; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nickeleres.key; # full path to SSL key

                # performance enhancement for SSL
                ssl_stapling on;
                ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
                ssl_session_timeout 5m;

                # safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-E$

                # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
                 # to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";

                # If your application is not compatible with IE <= 10, this will redirect visitors to a page advising a browser update
                # This works because IE 11 does not present itself as MSIE anymore
                if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE" ) {
                    return 303 https://browser-update.org/update.html;
                }

                # pass all requests to Meteor
                location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
                    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

                    # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
                    # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
                    # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
                    if ($uri != '/') {
                        expires 30d;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: added in original post

Comment: what is the browser request URL?

Comment: https://nickeleres.com

Comment: Is `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` still around? Remember to remove that if not using it or you might have conflicting directives.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/nginx/www/index.html is what nginx shows if you still have the symlink to *default* in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.

Nginx loads all of the config files in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/, which makes it easy to have configs for different sites on the same server.  The usual method is to store these config files in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and put a symlink to the ones you want to load in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.  By default, there's a file called *default* in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ with a symlink to it in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ so that an unconfigured server will show the default nginx index.html.

Removing /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default will remove the symlink (while preserving the actual config file, in case you need it later), preventing nginx from attempting to load /usr/share/nginx/www/index.html (which I guess you removed).